# Python error. Not getting the expecting output

Tags: python

```
     loweralphas=["a", "b","c","d","e","f"]
     upperalphas=["a", "b","c","d","e","f"]

       for loweralpha in loweralphas[:2]:
       print(loweralpha.title())
       for upperalpha in upperalphas:
        print (upperalphas.title()[loweralphas.index(loweralpha)*3:loweralphas.inde‌​x(loweralpha)*3+3])
```

I get the output like this....

```
    A
    A
    B
    B
```

but I need the output like this...

```
    a
    A
    B
    C

    b
    D
    E
    F
```

I need to get ABC under "a" and DEF under "b" and also I need to do that without capitalizing The letters in the list but it doesn't work. Also I don't need to extend the coding lines. 
I these restrictions send stupid but I need it like that.

Comment: what is the goal of this exercise? what you're asking for isn't clear

Comment: I just need to get the expected output.

Comment: Okay, well, this will do the trick: `print('a\nA\nB\nC\n\nb\nD\nE\nF')`  Now do you understand @RobbieMilejczak's question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
loweralphas=["a", "b","c","d","e","f"]
upperalphas=["a", "b","c","d","e","f"]

for index, lower in enumerate(loweralphas[:2]):
    print(lower)
    for upper in upperalphas[index*3:(index*3)+3]:
        print(upper.title())
    print()
```

Output:

```
a
A
B
C

b
D
E
F
```

Comment: What "index lower enumerate" does?

Comment: `enumerate` is a built in function of Python which retrieves both the element and its index from a structure such as a list. It makes it easier especially for your task where you have to switch starting point for `upperalphas` every time you want to print. So for every element in `loweralphas`, you can take both its `index` and `lower`, which is the element of the current index.

Comment: Got you bro............

Answer (score 0):

```
for a, x in zip(loweralphas, zip(*[map(str.title, upperalphas)]*3)):
   print(a, *x, sep='\n', end='\n\n')
```

Here's a solution using `zip` to split `upperalphas` into 3-wide groups, then zipping those groups with `loweralphas`.  The we can use python 3's handy `print` funciton to format the output

```
a
A
B
C

b
D
E
F
```